# Drive API - Trying to use ID of searched item but variable is not updating its value... But only getting 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm trying to search for a file in a team drive that my service account has access to and then store the files ID that came up to a variable and use this variable later on.

Problem here is that the variable never gets updated and only returns 'undefined'.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const privatekey = require("./service.json");

// Extracting SA Info
const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  privatekey.client_email,
  null,
  privatekey.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']);

// Authenticating SA
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("\nSuccessfully connected!");
    }
});

// Defining Google Drive API
const drive = google.drive('v3');

var testValue; //Trying to use this to get the ID of searched file

var fileName = "Red";
var teamDriveID = "x0s0s00s0s0s0s0";
var pageSize = 1;
var fields = "files(id, name, parents, size)";
var orderBy = "quotaBytesUsed desc";

// List Team Drive Files function
function listFiles(fileName, teamDriveID, pageSize, fields, orderBy) {
    drive.files.list({
        auth: jwtClient,
        q: `name contains '${fileName}' and mimeType contains 'video/'`, 
        pageSize: pageSize,
        supportsTeamDrives: true,
        teamDriveId: teamDriveID,
        includeTeamDriveItems: true,
        fields: fields,
        corpora: 'teamDrive',
        // orderBy: orderBy
    },
    function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('\nThe API returned an error: ' + err);
        return;
    } 
    const files = response.data.files;
    if (files.length == 0) {
        console.log("No files found...");
    } else {
            console.log('Found Files: ')
            for (const file of files) {
                console.log(`${file.name}` + " - " + "("+`${file.id}`+")" + " - " + `${file.parents}` + " -- " + `${file.size}`);
                testValue == file.id;
                return testValue;
            }
        }
    });
};

listFiles(fileName, teamDriveID, pageSize, fields, orderBy)

console.log(testValue) //printing testValue to check if its updated with item ID
```

Comment: sounds like something is wrong with your application of the fields parmanter but i am not sure what as it apears to work here https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?fields=files(id%252C+name%252C+parents%252C+size)&_h=2&

Comment: Well thats the thing - I can print out the variable using the console.log(`${file.id}` as I am doing in the else{} function near the end of the script. But once everything is run then its like it loses its value... Another strange thing is that when I try to run the .JS file the "console.log(testValue)" seems to be printed before the function is run, and gives a 'undefined' so it seems like it runs the console.log() and then runs my function, even though console.log() comes after... Super weird...

Comment: This is a common JavaScript async misunderstanding. All JS network calls are asynchronous and happen in the background after your final console.log had executed in the foreground.